# Which package to use to connect R with MongoDB?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I wonder what are the main differences between `rmongodb` and `RMongo` packages for connecting `R` with MongoDB. What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two packages?

Comment: Not sure why this question has been closed as I wasn't looking for a tool (I actually used `rmongodb` some time ago, so in that sense I have already found the tool), but instead asking for differences between two particular libraries, i.e., the features that are included in one of them but aren't included in the other one and vice versa. My question was not supposed to attract answers like "I like on of them more", but rather an objective comparison of the functionalities of these two libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
library(rmongodb)
```

your connection details will likely differ from these defaults

```
host <- "someone.com:10200"
username <- "myuser"
password <- "mypassword"
db <- "testdatabase"
```

connect to mongo and then create function has the following signature

```
mongo <- mongo.create(host=host , db=db, username=username, password=password)
```

Also

```
> library("RMongo")
> mongo  < - mongoDbConnect("db")
```

`RMango:` MongoDB Database interface for R. The interface is provided via Java calls to the mongo-java-driver.
`rmongodb:` This R package provides an interface to the NoSQL MongoDB database using the MongoDB C-driver.

While `RMongo` package is very straight-forward and user-friendly, it did take me a while to figure out how to specify a query with `rmongodb` package

Supported Functionality by rmongodb

- Connecting and disconnecting to MongoDB Querying, inserting and
- updating to MongoDB including with JSON and BSON Creating and
- handling BSON objects Dropping collections and databases on MongoDB
- Creating indices on MongoDB collections Error handling Executing
- commands on MongoDB Adding, removing, handling files on a "Grid File
- System" (GridFS) on a MongoDB server High Level functionality as
- mongo.apply, mongo.summary, mongo.get.keys, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are their any advantages of using Java vs. C driver? Is any of these packages more user-friendly than the other?

Comment: tomorrow night there is a webinar for rmongodb (https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/287023934). There I will talk in detail about differences. Short: rmongodb provides more functionaltiy and is more flexible for Big Data.

Comment: @AnjaM if this anwser is useful - upvote and select it as answer

Comment: @PrasannaNanda You've listed quite a few functionalities for `rmongodb`. Are any of them missing in `RMongo` and vice versa? I'm trying to decide to which of them I should stick. User-friendliness is of course one important point. But are there also differences in functionalities? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @MarkusSchmidberger Thanks, I've just registered for it!